# Compute where the hypotenus intersect with a circle

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

So I want to make a script that can draw various microscope darkfield filters.
in those you have 3 support bars with a 120° angle holding a circle inside a circle.

[image]

I came up with something but wrongfully calculated the blue triangle value while I should have computed the purple triangle value.

I had to wake up my 9 years old trigonometry knowledge and it worked however I can't figure a way to compute the purple triangle values.

Here is an image :

[image]

for now since I'm computing the blue triangle I get this result :

[image]

Would anyone know what I need to compute the purple triangle?

Thanks.

Comment: also in your picture I am pretty sure x2=rsin(c). But these are much more intuitive if done in terms of the central angle a. The tangent segment has length bc=r tan(a). And the secant segment has length ac= r sec(a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three intersect points will have coordinates (if circle center is 0,0), where `i = 0,1,2`:

```
for i = 0..2 do
   Fi = Pi/2 + i * 2 * Pi / 3  //probably -Pi/2 depending on your graphics coordinate system
   X = R * Cos(Fi)
   Y = R * Sin(Fi)
```

Comment: also AE=r, because it is a radius

Comment: thanks, it works really well, I don't understand the math tho.

Comment: Fi is angle of segment (bar). Top point is at Pi/2 (90 degrees) angle, others at 90+120 and 90+240 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially: **ac = r**;

For **de** we look at half the side of an equal sided triangle: **de = sin(a) = sin(30 degrees) = r/2**

When it comes to **ad** we can use Pythagoras to compute; **ad = cos(a)= cos(30 degrees) = r*sqrt(3)/2**:

Comment: Thanks, does it work well enough to be marked as completed and upvoted?